# SVNKit for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Trying to install Subversive and am choking on the concept of **Subversive Connectors**, and how to install them.

(1) **What are Subversive Connectors?** My only guess is that they help tie the Subversive plug-in to the local instance of **svn**. Yes? No?!?!

(2) I found an article explaining the difference between JavaHL and SVN Kit connectors (although it *didn't* explain what either of them were, or what they did!), and it looks like I want SVN Kit 1.3.2 for a number of reasons. But when I try to install them from the *Subversive Connector Discovery* dialog, it gives me an error, tells me to check an ambiguous "error log" (Eclipse error log, SVN error log, Subversive error log, ?!?!) and refuses to install it. I came across an article stating that this was a defect from a December 2009 release, but that it had been fixed. **What is going on here? I am using Helios on 64-bit Ubuntu, anybody else ever have this problem? Any suggestions for how to fix or circumvent?**

(3) It looks like the **Subversive Connector Discovery** dialog is configured to launch the first time you try to open Subversive from inside Eclipse (after installing and restarting). But since I wasn't able to install SVNKit 1.3.2, I canceled that dialog, closed Eclipse and walked away for a day. Now, I can't seem to get it to launch, and it has next to *no* online documentation that is helping me.  **Anybody know how to launch this dialog second and subsequent times?**

Thanks to anyone who can provide even the tiniest of help.  I will wash the gutters, mow the lawn and perform a full spring cleanup for anyone who can answer these!!!

Comment: I'm very surprised that a such a major IDE as Eclipse, and such a reputable VCS as Subversion, would have a plug-in between each other that was so poorly documented... if anyone knows of a good (thorough!) Subversive tutorial, don't hold back!!!

Comment: My suggestion is to use subclipse, in wich merging is a lot easyer, since interactive merge is present. Try it.

Comment: +1 for Subclipse. Also, it is easier to setup. It seems almost weekly that I see people with questions on how to install Subversive correctly, whereas Subclipse does the same things and "just works".

Answer (score 2):

Usually this works out pretty well, you install Subversive, and if you havn't installed a Connector, you get the dialog when Subversive needs it.

What's going on is a sad bug in the latest Eclipse/Subversive version.

Here's what worked for me.

Uninstall anything subversive related that you've installed.(Help->About Installation Details)

Go to http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php#early_access . Download the zip file, currently [this](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/subversive/0.7/builds/Subversive-incubation-0.7.9.I20101203-1700.zip) one.

Install that file you downloaded (Help->Install New Software , hit the Add button, chose Archive). 
A restart later, you'll be asked for an SVN connector, choose SVNKit with the biggest version number, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks nos! I'll give it a try after work today. What's the deal with this bug? Kind of major, don't you think!?!

Comment: Yes, I can't find the bugzilla report again now, but it's basically not going to be fixed until another release.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer subclipse, here's the link to the install instructions:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Answer (score 1):

In regards to part 3. You can install the connectors directly from Polarion's update site. From what I understand, this is what the **Subversive Connector Discovery** does under the covers. The links to their update site are found [here](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php) and look something like http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/luna-site/. In Eclipse, click Help->Install New Software and paste the link into the **"Work With"** box. That should give you the list of connectors you can install.